# Выгрузка данных с веб клиента 1c с помощью Python

Tags: python, 1с

День добрый, не могу понять устройства 1с и не понимаю откуда начать копать, задача следующая: компании дали доступ в веб клиент 1с , нужно выгружать данные оттуда, продублировать в свой и проверять актуальность , проблема в том, что открывается веб приложение, и одно дело залогиниться в нем(в чем тоже пока не разобрался), а другое осуществить переход по страницам, подскажите, как это можно осуществить?

P.S. Первый вопрос тут, не закидывайте помидорами
P.S.S. Подобного вопроса не нашел, возможно из за плохого знания 1с и неправильной формулировки вопроса

Всем спасибо, спарсил с помощью Seleniumа

Comment: 1с это платформа на базе которой построена уйма решений. Скорее всего готового варианта не будет. Посмотрите с точки зрения пользователя что требуется и порядок действий. И затем автоматизация через скрипты, как ответили ниже. Также просмотрите всю доступную документацию именно по тому продукту, с которым работаете. Могут появиться разные варианты.

Answer (score 0):

"Копать" надо начинать с ответа на вопрос: *Какие именно данные будут выгружаться из 1С ?* От этого и будет зависеть способ решения; В вакууме можно предложить два варианта:

1. На машине с которой заходим в 1С, устанавливаем AutoIT; Это скриптовый язык, который позволяет запустить прогу/активировать окно, затем сгенерировать клик мышью в указанную область и так далее (сделать паузу); Сможем полностью имитировать работу юзера 1С (делая клики в нужную область экрана)
2. Написать обработку в 1С (нужен доступ к конфигуратору, возможно Полные права); На машине где заходим в 1С, делаем ярлык в котором 1С запускается и выполняет нашу обработку после старта; Внутри 1С-обработки выполняем всё что нужно; Запуск ярлыка можем прописать в шедулере по расписанию;

Comment: 1. Нужно, чтоб работало в фоне, а скрипты не дадут какое то время пользоваться пк
2.Вот это интересно, но не понимаю, как 1с будет брать данные с чужого вебклиента, поэтому надеялся сделать все с помощью библиотек парсинга, но не могу обойти сообщение: "Данный браузер не поддерживается"
Пришел к выводу, что дело в редиректе и портах, но, опять же, все еще в поисках решения. 

Большое спасибо за ответы!

Comment: 1с не будет брать данные с чужого ... представь что мы заходим в вебклиент и кликаем пункт меню(выполняем свою обработку), так вот этот сценарий можно выполнить на сервере где развернута 1с в автоматическом режиме (пункт 2)